# HTMLUNIT - Exception invoking XMLHttpRequest.setWithCredentials()

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am having a trouble understanding the meaning of this HTMLUnit Exception.
It happens when i try to load the home page.

This is the first time I get this and I can't figure out why it's happening.
Here is the exception :

> ERROR com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener - Error during JavaScript execution'
> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking XMLHttpRequest.setWithCredentials() with arguments [Boolean]

Here are my webclient options :

```
webClient = new WebClient( BrowserVersion.CHROME );

webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(false);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```

And how I call the home page :

```
try {

  HtmlPage page  = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(base_url);

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  webClient.close();
}
```

Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This means the implementation of the property XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) throws an error. This happens because the page you are opening seems to do some ajax requests during loading.

From the source code i can not see any reason for this exception. Please provide the version of HtmlUnit and the whole stacktrace and i will have a look.
If the base_url is public it will be also a great help.

Comment: any chance to get the whole stacktrace - you can also send by private mail